# Jax-WS doesn't work with Form Authentification

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws

I have a Jave EE Webapplication with Tomcat and Servlets. 
I developed a Web-Service with Jax-WS.

If i deploy my Java EE with Basic Authentifictaion, it works all fine. 
But if i deploy my Java EE Project with Form Authentification, i become a error Message (Failed to access the WSDL)

So i don't know how i can do the authentificaton with Form Authentification.

My WebService Code is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final String PASSWORD = "password";

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(
                "username",
                PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        }
    });


    URL wsdlUrl = new URL("https://.../.../sayhello?wsdl");

    QName qname = new QName("http://webservice.src/", "WebServiceImplService");

    Service service = Service.create(wsdlUrl, qname);
    WebServiceInterface helloWorldInterface = service.getPort(WebServiceInterface.class);

    System.out.println(helloWorldInterface.authentification());
```

}

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://.../.../sayhello?wsdl.
```

This error exists because the authentfication wasn't successfully. 
With Basic authentfication it works fine.

I don't know where the difference is.

Comment: Can you please detail your problem description and post full error message?

Comment: What does your `helloWorldInterface.authentification()` method do?. As @VigneshVino said you need to elaborate with more data. The question isnt clear.